# How can I use real superior figures for footnote marks in beamer?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, superscripts

I have a font that offers real superiors and I want to make use of them for the footnote marks in beamer. So I thought I could just set the respective command for the beamer font of `footnote mark`, but as you can see with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mintspirit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test\footnote{my footnote}

\setbeamerfont{footnote mark}{series=\sufigures}

Test\footnote{my footnote}

Test\sufigures 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It actually leads to a superior-superior number, because now the superior 2 is shrinked and moved upwards through the footnote command, see

[image]

and

[image]

respectively. What would be the way to tell beamer to use the superior figures for the footnote marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mintspirit}
\setbeamerfont{footnote mark}{series=\sufigures}

\makeatletter
% remove \@textsuperscript from \@makefnmark,
% which is redefined by beamer in beamerbaseframecomponents.sty
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \hbox{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Test text superscript \textsuperscript{0123456789} \par
  Test superiors number {\sufigures 0123456789}
  
  Test footnote\footnote{a}\footnote{b}\footnote{c}\footnote{d}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution @muzimuzhiZ, it works for me! But could a user possibly redefine the footnote to use "regular" superscript by just redefining the `footnote mark` font?

Comment: @TobiBS Looking through the supported options of `\setbeamerfont`, I'm afraid it's impossible. `\textsuprscript{#1}` uses sth. like `\ensuremath{^{\mbox{#1}}`. I don't think `\setbeamerfont`, inserted in the `#1`, can restore the effect of baseline lifting caused by super script `^{...}`.

Comment: Alternatively, to achieve more flexible style configuration for footnote mark, one can define a new beamer template `footnote mark` (and change related internal codes in beamer). But then the required change to use real superior number in footnote marks is still "removing `\textsuperscript` from new template".